# C# DirectorySearcher filter

Tags: c#, ldap

I am trying to fetch records from LDAP using DirectorySearcher. The following is the filter I am using:

> (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(employeeType=A))

I need to modify this filter to fetch records for employeeType either A or B.

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Expression you want to replace employeeType=A by employeeType=A OR employeeType=B

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(employeeType=A))
```

So you replace `(employeeType=A)` by `(|(employeeType=A)(employeeType=B))` and get

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(employeeType=A)(employeeType=B)))
```